# Question regarding Multi Source Inventory

Tags: magento2.4.5, msi, multi-source-inventory

I'm using Magento Community Edition.

I would like to define two different Inventory Sources in 2 different EU countries. When a customer orders a product does Multi Source Inventory automatically pick the cheapest (in terms of shipping) available source? From what I read, this feature might only be available in the Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi Source Inventory (MSI) is a core feature of Magento 2 Community Edition and Enterprise Edition. It allows you to manage inventory across multiple sources, such as warehouses or retail locations, and allocate stock to orders based on various criteria.

In terms of selecting the cheapest available source for an order, MSI does not have this capability out of the box. However, you could use a third-party extension or custom development to achieve this functionality. For example, you could create a custom algorithm that evaluates the available sources based on their inventory levels, shipping cost, and other factors, and then selects the optimal source for each order.

It's also worth noting that MSI provides a range of tools and APIs for managing sources and inventory, including inventory reservations, source priority, and source selection rules. With these tools, you can customize how inventory is allocated to orders and optimize your fulfillment process based on your specific business needs.

In summary, while MSI does not have a built-in feature for selecting the cheapest available source, it does provide a flexible framework for managing inventory across multiple sources and can be extended to meet a variety of fulfillment requirements.

Comment: Thank you, very insightful!
Although this does look like a ChatGpt answer :D.

Comment: Yup, you caught that well. :)